# Differentiate between real words and random strings

Tags: php

I am looking to differentiate a valid english word from random strings.

In the following list

```
apple
bc3cd7410a8ee1defc4461cd902f
pears
banana
banannna
```

I need to filter out `bc3cd7410a8ee1defc4461cd902f`

Right now my approach is to use `pspell_check` and `pspell_suggest` to guess if it is a valid (or a genuine misspelling)

```php
function isNotRadomString($stringToCheck)
    {
        $dictionary = pspell_new('en');
        if (!pspell_check($dictionary, $stringToCheck)) {
            ## check if user intended to provide an actual word and misspelled it
            if (!empty(pspell_suggest($dictionary, $stringToCheck))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

The function currently works as expected for the given list of words. However, I have a feeling there must be a better way to deal with the situation, especially when I am relying on `pspell_suggest` in a way that is not its intended use.

So the question here is under what circumstances can `pspell_suggest` provide suggestions for junk words like `yhsfolh` or other situations that I cannot think of now.

I was thinking will calculating the `[Levenshtein distance][1]` between the input and the first suggestion from `pspell_suggest` make any difference in the results.

Comment: You mention that you want to filter out junk to keep only "_valid english word[s]_".  The only certain way to achieve that is to use a dictionary like you are, surely?  Of course, you can immediately remove anything with a number in, but I'm not sure what else

Comment: This really depends on your use-case, I think. Overall your idea sounds like a really great one for simple, everyday scenarios. The new function also has options such as `PSPELL_BAD_SPELLERS` which may or may not be helpful.

Comment: @Martin Re numbers: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/332907/583

Comment: @deceze I hadn't even considered words such as that which would include numbers.  An interesting point!